# Installing CakeDC Users plugin - Error Plugin Users could not be found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model, cakedc

Hi all Iam currently trying to install the CakeDC/users plugin using https://github.com/CakeDC/users and have come across an error.

When I run command './Console/cake schema create users --plugin Users' I get the error message:

**Error: Plugin Users could not be found. 
0 C:\wamp\www\toppin\lib\cake\console\shell.php(376): CakePlugin::load('Users')**

I have tried loading both the users and migrations plugins using CakePlugin::loadAll(); and individually using  CakePlugin::load('pluginhere');

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, solved :

Just go to your 'app' dir, not 'app\Console' and run 'Console\cake schema create users --plugin Users'

It worked fine, I'm using xampp under windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You are working in your `app` folder I assume? If you are calling your plugin Users it should be loaded with `CakePlugin::load('Users')` and then it should be in your `app/Plugin/Users` folder.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I have already fulfilled this requirement, thanks anyway, I think it has something to do with the way Iam trying to run it from the console, any other ideas are welcome :).